# How can I take in user input that has a number separated by a decimal point and store that input as an int without the decimal point?

Tags: c

I want to understand fully the best way to work with Money in older languages like C.  I understand that the best way would be to store the money as integers since money is actually an integer though we format it in a way that makes it look at times like a decimal.  For example, you cannot really ever have fractional cents in real life, etc.

What I want to do is create a simple example program that will allow the user to input 12.59.  Then I would take that 12.59 input they gave, extract the decimal point and simple store an int as 1259.  How do I do this?

My next problem comes in displaying the result to the user.  How do I take my int of 1259 and only format it to display a decimal point in between the last two numbers of the integer?

Comment: You can have *money* in fractions of cents, you just can't have *cash* in fractions of cents.

Comment: @chris You can't store money as float or double.  That leads to floating point rounding errors because of floating point imprecision.

Comment: @Beta You can have operations performed on money that result in fractional cents that are then rounded.  Money is never stored with a fractional cent that I know of.

Comment: could these links help? [Q number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29) and [fixed-point math](http://x86asm.net/articles/fixed-point-arithmetic-and-tricks/)

Comment: "you cannot really ever have fractional cents in real life"  Hmmm: Rates today are often in fraction of cents like 299.9 cents/gallon.  US had [Half-cents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_cent_(United_States_coin)) and my crystal ball says withing 10 years, US will round all to the nearest 0.05.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply multiplying the user input by 100 for storage and then simply divide it by 100 again when displayed/used?

Comment: I would have to treat it as a float at some point to do that though, right?

Comment: You would have to extract it from the user input as a float but you could change it to a decimal immediately. Depending on further accuracy requirements you could raise the original multiplier by factors of 10 to work with tenth's and hundredth's of cents etc.

Comment: @igloodan No, you don't have to *ever* treat it as a float.  `scanf("%d.%d", &dollars, &cents);  money = (dollars * 100) + cents;`.

Comment: @Timbram Monetary values are sometimes stored with fractions of cents, if a transaction for 1,000,000 units of a product and it cost $0.015 rather than a rounded up $0.02 it equates to a $50 difference!

Comment: @igloodan Yeah that is an interesting point!.  And now that I think about it I feel like I have seen some times where fractional money values occur.  I guess it really just depends on how the system you use handles money and to what fractional amount it would let you go down to.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart  "don't have to _ever_ treat it as a float."  How do you propose to calculate [Monthly payment formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula) using integer arithmetic?

Comment: @chux Ok, not *ever*, but my whole point was that "[extracting] it from the user input as a float" is unnecessary if you know it is in dollars and (whole) cents.

Answer (score 1):

the part before comma is `x / 100` (integer divide, not floating point) and the part after comma is `x % 100` (make sure x is positive):

```
unsigned x;
...
printf("%u,%02u", x / 100, x % 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

When reading floating point textual input as 2 integers as in money, certain precautions are needed: Range, Sign, extra space, distinguish ".02" from ".2".  A challenge is making certain there is no space, nor sign before the 2nd number (cents).  Also if the leading (dollar) amount is negative, so is the 2nd amount.

```
// 1: success, -1: EOF, 0: invalid input
int ReadCents(long long *amount) {
  long long dollar;
  int n;
  char cent[3];
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return -1;
  int count = sscanf(buf, "%lld.%2[0-9] %n", &dollar, cent, &n);
  // all fields read?
  // cent has 2 digits?
  // no trailing junk?
  if (count != 2 || cent[1] == '\0' || buf[n]) return 0;
  *amount = dollar * 100 + ((dollar < 0) ? -1 : 1) * atoi(cent);
  return 1;
}
```

Could add test for integer overflow.

To print out use divide and remainder. Watch out for negative numbers.

```
long long amount;
printf("%d.%02d", amount/100, abs(amount%100));
```

---

"to store the money as integers since money is actually an integer" over-simplifies the issues of money and data representation.  Using floating-point, integer, or decimal floating point all have strengths and weaknesses when dealing with values that need sub-integer accuracy.  As the post queries how to read/write an integer based solution, the above answers addresses that issue.

Comment: `[0-9]` is implementation-defined, some systems may not support it

Comment: @Matt McNabb True, code could use `[0123456789]` for those compilers.